# making calculator using JS

Tags: javascript

How do Iput dot "." in textbox by button using JS?

It is concatenating the string, when I checked with an alert() https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rjUm.jpg, and not displaying in the textbox,

It shows the warning ["The specified value '5.' cannot be parsed, or is out of range."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXmYJ.jpg)

**[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueGX3.jpg)**

```
function display(n){
  document.cal.dis.value += n;
}

function dot1(){
  alert(document.cal.dis.value = document.cal.dis.value + ".");
    document.cal.dis.value = document.cal.dis.value + ".";
}
```

Comment: Please don't put your code as image. No one has time for rewriting your code from picture for reproducing error.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] - [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let yourNumber = 6;
```

//your mechanisms of adding dot so it will be 6.

```
let formattedNumber = yourNumber.toFixed(1); // Display "6.0"
```